# Passing drawer to Navigator views

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to pass a drawer to different views so they can open it at the click of the button.

index.js - Created the drawer here

```
renderScene(route, navigator) {
    var Component = ROUTES[route.name];
    return <Component route={route} navigator={navigator} api={new Api()} session={new Session()} style={globalStyle} {...route.passProps} />;
}

render() {
    return (
        <Drawer
            ref={(ref) => { this._drawer = ref; } }
            type="overlay"
            tweenDuration={150}
            //content={<SideBar navigator={this._navigator} />}
            tapToClose
            acceptPan={false}
            onClose={() => this.closeDrawer()}
            openDrawerOffset={0.2}
            panCloseMask={0.2}
            styles={{
                drawer: {
                    shadowColor: '#000000',
                    shadowOpacity: 0.8,
                    shadowRadius: 3,
                },
            }}
            tweenHandler={(ratio) => {
                return {
                    drawer: { shadowRadius: ratio < 0.2 ? ratio * 5 * 5 : 5 },
                    main: {
                        opacity: (2 - ratio) / 2,
                    },
                };
            } }
            negotiatePan
            >
            <Navigator
                ref={(ref) => { this._navigator = ref; } }
                initialRoute={{ name: 'home', passProps: { drawer: this._drawer } }}
                renderScene={this.renderScene}
                />
        </Drawer>
    );
}
```

home.js - this is where the header and footer is as well as the open drawer button.

```
render() {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Header>
                <Button transparent onPress={this.props.drawer.open()}>
                    <Icon name="ios-menu" />
                </Button>
                <Title>Botulo.</Title>
            </Header>

            <Content>
                <Text>{this.props.user.display}</Text>
            </Content>

            <Footer>
                <FooterTab>
                    <Button transparent>
                        <Icon name='ios-person' />
                    </Button>
                    <Button transparent>
                        <Icon name='ios-grid-outline' />
                    </Button>
                    <Button transparent>
                        <Icon name='ios-chatboxes' />
                    </Button>
                </FooterTab>
            </Footer>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

The problem is that in home.js, 'this.props.drawer' is undefined.

What is the correct way to pass the drawer instance and call open/close() on it.

Thanks for you help.

Ark.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass down the openDrawer handler down to the *home* component, and then call it on click, or press.

when you render home component pass down onClick like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.openDrawer = this.openDrawer.bind(this)
}

this.openDrawer() {
    this.setState({ drawerOpen: true })
}

render() {

    let drawer = null
    if (this.state.drawerOpen) {
        drawer = (
            <Drawer 
               {/* whatever props you need */}
            />
        )
    }

    return (
        <Container>
         { drawer }
         <Home 
             onClick={this.openDrawer}
             {/* whatever else props you need */}
         />
        </Container>
    );
}
```

finally in home you do this

```
render() {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Header>
                <Button transparent onPress={this.props.onClick}>
                    <Icon name="ios-menu" />
                </Button>
                <Title>Botulo.</Title>
            </Header>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

you can see that once the user clicks on the button to open the drawer, then the drawer component will be rendered.

does this make sense to you?